# Simple parsing of html file for <U></U> values in .net?

Tags: .net, html, parsing

Looking for a simple means in .NET to parse an html file to get back all values within `<u></u>` tags.

Ex: `<U>105F</U>`

There may be many of these in the file with other tags but all I need is to loop through and get back a list of all the values so they cna then be processed.

Looking for a light small way to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely Regular expressions:

```
Dim myPattern As String = "<U>(.*?)</U>"

    For Each thisMatch As Match In System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(myPage1HTML, myPattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            Response.write(thisMatch.ToString)
    Next
```

Comment: -1 for suggesting parsing HTML with regular expressions. See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000253.html

Comment: Regex worked fine in my case as the html is very clean and specific to the content each time.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML document is well formed, XPath would be my first choice.

Requested code example (never tested thou);

```
var doc                    = new XPathDocument (@"path\to\file.html");
XPathNavigator navigator   = doc.CreateNavigator ();
XPathNodeIterator iterator = navigator.Select ("//U");
while (iterator.MoveNext ())
    Console.WriteLine ("U: {0}", iterator.Current.Value);
```

Comment: It is well formed with all matchign tags and very basic html.  Do you have a sample of usign XPath for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("//u");
```

Gets you the list of `U` nodes

Answer (score 0):

sample for using Xpath with XMLDocument

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file.html");

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//u");
foreach (XmlNode title in nodeList) {
    Console.WriteLine(title.InnerXml);
}
```

its taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.selectnodes.aspx)

Comment: The problem here is its pretty fragile.  If there's any html thats not well formed, this wont work.

Comment: true, but he specifically wrote the xhtml is well formed in his comment below

Answer (score -2):

[Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack).

I **strongly** advise against using regular expressions for parsing HTML. They're a great tool, but they're not suited to this job. HTML is just too complex. As soon as you hit one of the edge cases (embedded tags, nested tags, etc.) you'll see what I mean.

EDIT: See also [Coding Horror: Parsing: Beyond Regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000253.html)